# Downloading an image to client that is stored as a variable

Tags: php, image, download

I have a fairly basic PHP script used to generate an image by combining several files, using variables stored in the URL, into one. For ease of explanation, here it is:

```
<?php

$images = array( $_GET['item1'], $_GET['item2'], $_GET['item3'] );

// Allocate new image
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(480, 480);
// Make alpha channels work
imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, true);

foreach($images as $fn) {
    // Load image
    $cur = imagecreatefrompng($fn);
    imagealphablending($cur, true);
    imagesavealpha($cur, true);

    // Copy over image
    imagecopy($img, $cur, 0, 0, 0, 0, 480, 480);

    // Free memory
    imagedestroy($cur);
}   

header('Content-Type: image/png');  // Comment out this line to see PHP errors
imagepng($img);

?>
```

No issue with that.

I don't really understand what to do with this now though. I would like to download this to the client's downloads folder but I am unaware of and cannot find any methods for this.

I do not particularly need someone to do this for me, but just a push in the right direction for resources on doing this.

I know how to do this by temporary storing that file as a .png on my server and directing the user to a download link for that but that seems like the long way around this.

Any help please?

-Tim

Answer (score 0):

You should save your code within a php file i.e. **image.php**. If a user calls this file passing valid arguments like this

```
www.example.com/image.php?item1=bild1.png&item2=bild2.png&item3=bild3.png
```

the file will be displayed within the browser (you don't have to save it on server side). To force a download of the image add an additional header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=image.png');
```

Comment: Alright thank you very much. Where did the name image.png come from? Is that the save name or the source name?

Comment: Tested it and found it for myself. Thanks

Comment: This works for Android and web use but produces no response on iOS. Is there a reason for this?